# How to get the dates for all mondays between two dates but only for whole weeks within the range with PHP?

Tags: php, date

Example: $startDate is Sunday 2021-06-20 and $endDate is Wednesday 2021-07-07. Then I want it to list:

```
Monday 2021-06-21
Monday 2021-06-28
```

But not Monday 2021-07-05 because the whole(monday thru sunday) week is not within the range. I figured I need the find the last Sunday within the range and use that date as the endDate.

Comment: You mean not *not Monday 2021-07-05*

Comment: actually getting confused when i read this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
function isMonday($date) {
    return $date->format('N') === '1';  
}

function isSunday($date) {
    return $date->format('N') === '7';  
}

function getMondays($start, $end) {
    $mondays = [];

    $datePeriod = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
    foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
        if (isMonday($date)) $mondays[] = $date;
    }
    if (!isSunday($end)) array_pop($mondays);
    return $mondays;
}

$startDate = new DateTime('2021-06-20');
$endDate = new DateTime('2021-07-07');
var_dump(getMondays($startDate, $endDate));
```

[3v4l Demo](https://3v4l.org/Il6Db). It's rather direct: there's a [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) Traversable object created from $start and $end dates with 1 day interval, that is iterated with foreach; each date that's a Monday is stored in an array. Last step is discarding the very last item of that array if the endDate is not Sunday.